# Calculate quantile for a whole matrix

Tags: r, statistics

For the working purposes, I need to find the overall quantile cut points for a matrix. I know I can "unlist" or "break" the matrix into two dimensional column and R can easily apply "quantile" function for a vector.

However, once I unlist the matrix and calculate the quantile, I don't know how to recover the unlisted data to the original one. Can someone tell me a method that can achieve this? Or are there some alternative ways to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem very clear on your data structures. If you actually have an object of class `matrix` there is no need to `unlist` or anything else, you can call `quantile` directly on a matrix:

```
> m = matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
> quantile(m, probs = c(.25, .5, .75))
  25%   50%   75% 
25.75 50.50 75.25
```

If you have a `data.frame`, then you do need to `unlist` (or convert to matrix with `as.matrix`), but you do not need to overwrite your saved data frame.

```
> my_df = data.frame(c1 = 1:5, c2 = 11:15)
> quantile(unlist(my_df), probs = c(.25, .5, .75))
  25%   50%   75% 
 3.25  8.00 12.75 
> my_df
  c1 c2
1  1 11
2  2 12
3  3 13
4  4 14
5  5 15
```

Notice at the end that `my_df` is still a data frame. As long as you don't re-assign `my_df` with the unlisted version, it will not be changed.